# Getting Invalid Operation Exception Sorting a Datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Here is my problem, I have a form (we name it F_report), in this form I have a datagridview that I add some columns programmatically and fill them.
My F_report form is used in many other forms to see the results of so many reports.

Some of this reports need datagridview columns to be sortable but some of them must have notsortable mode.

I used this code in reports that I want notsortable columns when adding new columns to my datagridview

```
For j = 0 To F_report.dgv_report.ColumnCount - 1
    F_report.dgv_report.Columns(j).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
Next
```

This code works fine but I have a problem, when I click on datagridview's column header I get some strange exeption like this :

```
Column header's SortGlyphDirection cannot be set to Ascending while the column's SortMode is set to NotSortable.
```

I don't want this error to be shown, What can I do?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please mention how you are providing data to your data grid view. Are you populating it using code  or you are setting its data source to a datatable or a collection ?

If you are setting its datasource, you will not be able to sort data grid view. In that case you need to sort your datasource

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I provided my data simply like this :

 F_report.dgv_report.Item("MyColumn", MyRow).Value = "SampleString"

Comment: So, I hope you had all columns to your dgv_report.Columns.Add(MyColumn); And MyColumn.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;

Comment: But I don't want my datagridview columns to be sortable

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
//Manage mouse click here
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help, I had ColumnHeaderMouseClick event already but my error is shown before ColumnHeaderMouseClick even fiers

Comment: Okay try this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/9addc65a-4ac0-42f4-94cd-1378f115c072/datagridview-column-header-selection-and-sorting